# How to find does Span<T> contains other Span<T> in the same order

Tags: c#

I want to check does a `Span<T>` contains a `Span<T>` elements in the same order.

```
Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[] { 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4 };

Span<byte> needle1 = stackalloc byte[] { 2, 5, 3 }; // this one is contained in buffer in the same order
Span<byte> needle2 = stackalloc byte[] { 2, 5, 4 }; // this one is not contained in buffer in the same order
```

I'm aware I can use `Span<T>.Contains()` that takes only one element as parameter to find the first element of needle in the buffer and then manually compare next elements one by one, but this seems highly suboptimal and tedious process.

`Span<T>.Overlaps()` is not the answer here, because needle is not stored in the same memory address as buffer. I'd like to avoid LINQ, because of performance reasons. Is there additional method in the standard library I am missing?

Comment: You can use `IndexOf`, which accepts another Span as argument, to check whether source Span contains "sequence" from target Span. E.g. `var contains = buffer.IndexOf(needle1) >= 0;`. With provided examples, `needle1` has index 2, `needle2` has inder -1 (so means source `buffer` doesn't contains sequence of bytes from `needle2`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MemoryExtensions.IndexOf<T>(this Span<T> span, ReadOnlySpan<T> value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-memoryextensions-indexof-1(system-span((-0))-system-readonlyspan((-0)))):

> Searches for the specified sequence and returns the index of its first occurrence. Values are compared using `IEquatable{T}.Equals(T)`.

> **Returns**  `Int32`
> The index of the occurrence of the `value` in the `span`. If not found, returns -1.

```
var contains1 = buffer.IndexOf(needle1) >= 0;
var contains2 = buffer.IndexOf(needle2) >= 0;
```